# What's the reason for css styling not working for div container, but changeable and visible in inspect mode?

Tags: css, vuejs2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>erjan_vue</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body> 
    <div id="erjan_vue_1">
     <h1>events tutorial</h1>

      <div id="canvas" v-on:mousemove="updateXY">{{x}}, {{y}}</div>

    </div>

    <script src = "main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it's only visible when I change it in inspect chrome mode. I can change its bg color and see it:
[image: jj]

Actual styles.css not working:

```css
#canvas{
    padding:200px 20px;
    border: 5px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    border-color: red;
    background-color: red;
    width: 500px; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

taken from the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCwOPBxsXDs&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gQcYgjhBoeQH7wiAyZNrYa&index=5)

Comment: where is the canvas id?

Comment: @Anfuca, canvas id is "canvas" , div id = "canvas"

Comment: just checking, the ID of the div in your screeshot is "re4", but you're targeting "#canvas" -- have you tried applying the css to "#re4"?

Comment: @ClaraB, yes I did , i did check the consistency of IDs, named them properly, i think it has to do with actual vue js messing with styles here!

Comment: Inline styles take priority over CSS unless teh css class has !important next to each style. Not sure if you added those inline styles yourself or if there is a javascript file adding those styles for you, but that's the culprit.

Comment: @SazzadHossain, there should be vue js <styles> in a separate file, but absent in my project folder.. maybe this is the reason

Comment: @ERJAN Seems like your vue javascript is probably relevant then -- could you share that as well?

Comment: @SazzadHossain i just added inline styles - one huge blob of code and it worked! thx!!!!

Comment: @SazzadHossain, if you want get points - you can make an answer, I will accept it! thx!

Comment: @ERJAN It's all right. Not answering for points. :-D

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial I m following was written a year ago(april 2017) and has no actual app.vue file which should have 3 things:

```
<template>

<script>

<styles>
```

Now this "styles" is where css stuff should go to.

I followed the advice of Sazzad Hosan from the comments above and just added a very ugly inline style:

```
 <div style="padding:200px 20px;
      border: 5px solid red;
      height: 200px;
      border-color: red;
      background-color: red;
      width: 500px; 
      text-align: center;" id="canvas" v-on:mousemove="updateXY">{{x}}, {{y}}</div>

    </div>
```

And it worked, like Sazzad said - "inline styles" take precedence over others.